# Given many-world interpretations, can we send a message to one of them?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

We have a sequence of 104 (13 * 8) independent boxes with 0 and 1 quantum states superimposed in each. We want to send 'Hello, world!' message to 1 world out of the many. So we say, if after measuring states in all the boxes, they say 'Hello, world!' in ASCII we deem the message received. If there's one world only, the chance of us receiving the message is small (0.5 ^ 104). If, assuming my understanding is correct, there is a different world for each quantum state combination, there will be a world that receives the message.

Apologies if the question doesn't make sense (I have only read-few-popular-science-articles knowledge) or if the question had already been asked - I did not see it in a "similar questions" list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This concept has been thought of and it's called the "Everett phone." It's been said that standard QM **does not** allow different branches to communicate with each other. However, some non-standard modifications to the dynamics of QM do allow Everett phones. See [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133543) that mentions some references.

Answer (score -3):

Yes but they wouldnt be able to answer us back because we would have already splitted from that parallel universe.

In fact if we find such a message it will be proof the the Many-World interpretation of QM is the correct one.

But where should we look for that kind of message possibly sent by a different version of me and you?