# Physical Meaning of Linear dependence of vectors in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

I have got some questions regarding the mathematical concepts in Quantum Mechanics that I have listed below-
1) What is the physical meaning of linear dependence of vectors in Quantum Mechanics ?
2) Actually, what is so special about Hilbert space due to which wavefunctions are defined on it ?

Comment: Maybe you can use the search bar to look around on the forum to find older answers to questions that address some of these issues.

Comment: In the Schrödinger case the absolute squares of wave functions (or state vectors) representing a state of a system are proportional to probability densities so they must be integrable. This naturally leads to a Hilbert space of square integrable functions in which the Schródinger operator acts. Linear dependence of two wave functions means that they represent the same physical state.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1201/2451 and links therein.